# How do Rails gems get installed?

Tags: rubygems

So for example I see a gem on GitHub, let's say this:
https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

and installation is just as easy as saying gem install awesome_print

So how do they get installed? I mean with that command how does it "know" where to find a gem with that name? and "where" does it install it to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gem, and commands to manipulate it are part of the rubygems software.

Comment: so all those gems are already on my system and with "gem install" I am  just activating them? then what if the gem author on GitHub updates his gem?

Comment: When you do `bundle install` the system first checks your system against the rubygems master repository and if any gems have been updated and if so the new versions are downloaded to your machine.  To avoid this you can add the version number ti the gem in the gemfile but then you have frozen to a version which is not recommended unless there is a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this: [New gem with bundler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)

The easiest way to answer your question is to make your own gem.